# xwatermark allpages does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: luatex, ubuntu, xwatermark

I have a document that typesets fine with MikTeX on Windows. I have tried the same source on Ubuntu but I am getting an error:

```
! Package xwatermark Error: No page specifier for watermark: 
||{\fontspec {Georgia}Confidential.}||.

See the xwatermark package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

The watermark related bit is this:

```
\newwatermark[allpages,textcolor=gray!35,
  fontsize=1.5cm,textangle=60]{{\fontspec{Georgia}Confidential.}}
```

The xwatermark version appears to be 1.5.2a, February 2012.

Is this a known problem? Are there any workarounds?

**UPDATE**

This is Ubuntu Raring, in case it matters.

**UPDATE 2**

Reduced complete test case:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\newwatermark[allpages,textcolor=gray!35,
  fontsize=1.5cm,textangle=60]{{Confidential.}}

\title{Title}
\author{Václav Zeman}
\date{2013-05-31}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 3**

I have submitted a problem report to Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1186407

Comment: The operating system doesn't matter at all, but add `\listfiles` to your document preamble and compare the version number log in each case see which packages differ

Comment: @cmhughes: Updated.

Comment: I really don't know the reason for the weird error. You have certainly given the page specifier in `[allpages,textcolor=gray!35,
  fontsize=1.5cm,textangle=60]`. I don't use Ubuntu. Please try version 1.5.2d, available at [CTAN/xwatermark](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark). If the problem persists, Ubuntu users may help us.

Comment: The updated MWE gives the error `! LaTeX Error: No \title given.` unless you supply a title with `\title{}` That is the standard behaviour for article class `\maketitle`. If you supply a title it runs without error (texlive 2012)

Comment: @AhmedMusa: I have tried the latest xwatermark version from CTAN. Unfortunately, it fails with other package version error. I am reluctant to modify more files in my otherwise working system.

Comment: wilx and @AhmedMusa I use TeX Live2013 in Ubuntu, but I don't think the OS has anything to do with his problem. The code given under "Update 2" runs OK in my system. Perhaps wilx is using outdated packages.

Comment: I just had this same problem. My workaround was removing `allpages` and replacing it with `pages=1-\lastdocpage`.