# Error concerning xwatermark package after updating package list

Tags: xwatermark

I have a problem, that came up after updating the whole package list of Miktex, and I am 100% sure it is due to the package `xwatermarks`.
After compiling the text I get the following error, right before `\begin{document}`:

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup
\let \BeforeStartOfDocument \@firstofone \cpt@beforest...
l.161 \begin{document}
```

I am sure because removing the usage of `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}` the documents get properly compiled.

Below I report my full preamble (so as to be 100% accurate in my topic); I would like to ask if someone can help me in using `xwatermarks` anyhow and avoid the problem. As far as the final document anything is fine, it is enough to remove `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}`.

Thank you in advance for any eventual help.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{booktabs}       
        
\usepackage[english]{babel}
                            
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\ddmmyyyydate
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%%\new[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT} %Questo mette la filigrana sotto l'immagine
%%\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!10,angle=45,scale=2,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT \today} %Questo mette la filigrana sopra l'immagine





\usepackage[TABTOPCAP, FIGBOTCAP]{subfigure}
\newcommand{\figbox}[1]{%
  \fcolorbox{white}{white}{
    \vbox to 6.5 cm{%
    \vfil
    \hbox to 8 cm{%
      \hfil
      #1%
      \hfil}%
    \vfil}}}

\newcommand{\Bfigbox}[1]{%
  \fcolorbox{white}{white}{%
    \vbox to 5.6 cm{%
    \vfil
    \hbox to 7 cm{%
      \hfil
      #1%
      \hfil}%
    \vfil}}}   

\newcommand{\Cfigbox}[1]{%
  \fcolorbox{white}{white}{%
    \vbox to 4.5 cm{%
    \vfil
    \hbox to 6.4 cm{%
      \hfil
      #1%
      \hfil}%
    \vfil}}}

\makeatletter
\def\subfigtopskip{4pt}
\def\subfigbottomskip{4pt}
\def\subfigcapskip{2pt}
\subtabletopcaptrue






\makeatletter
\def\printtitle{
                {\centering \Large \normalfont \textbf{\@title}\par}}

\def\piedipagina{%                  
    { \textup{\@title}}}    
    
\makeatother

\title{\large{Title}}



\makeatletter
\def\printauthor{
    {\large \@author}}
\makeatother

\author{%
    \textup{dt. Giacomo Del Bianco} \\
    \textup{Research \& Development \footnotesize{\textsc{Reactive Hot-Melts}}} \\
    \vspace{50pt}
    \textup{\today}\\
    }


%%% Headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}   

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\footnotesize{\lfoot{\footnotesize ~\scshape{\piedipagina} $\cdot$ \footnotesize\today}}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}



\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\setlength\absleftindent{10pt}
\setlength\absrightindent{10pt}
\abslabeldelim{\quad}
\setlength{\abstitleskip}{-10pt}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\small \slshape}

\textheight = 22 cm


\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura} 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Indice delle figure} 
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Indice delle tabelle} 

%%% Start of the document
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: xwatermark is not compatible with a current latex (it uses catoptions). Use something else.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike! Do you know what package could I use?

Comment: eso-pic, or simply the in-built shipout/background hook: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573331/2388

Comment: Thank you very much Ulrich! If you officially answer the question, I approve your answer.

Comment: My name is Ulrike, not Ulrich. And I will vote to close it as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/566088/2388

Comment: Yes, it uses `tikzpicture`, I use it often. Thank you again Ulrike.